# source / header files not being created when I export a template containing them

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, ide

1. Create a new project
2. add 2 files, driver.h (under header files) and a driver.cpp (under source files)
3. Add content such as #include's to the header file, and include that header file to the .cpp file
4. file < export template
5. project template, click next.
6. add template name, description, don't care for icon or image so leave blank.
7. finish, then create a project using the above template.

Now I have a zip folder in my exported templates containing the template we named above (we'll just say project template). The problem is, when I create a new project using this template, the .h and .cpp files are referenced in the solution explorer, but they do not exist:
[image]

And if I try clicking on driver.cpp or driver.h, I get the following error
[image]

But if I paste in the driver.h and driver.cpp files into this location, they work
[image]

It defeats the purpose of having a template if I have to paste in the files for this to work, why is it that these files are missing and yet exist in file explorer? Why is this not saving the contents of the template I exported? What do I need to do to make the template create the two missing driver.cpp and driver.h files automatically so I don't have to go through this process every time I create a project that needs these same files?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
The issue is that there is a bug in the VS Export Template routine that is not copying files that are organized in project subfolders. ex. ..\Source Files\driver.cpp

This is what I did as a workaround

1. Delete the old (messed up) templates:  goto -> C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ProjectTemplatesCache
   Delete the xxxx.zip directories you don't want anymore.
2. Close and ReOpen Visual Studio. (you can check if the templates are gone - File/New/Project ...
3. Create your project as you would like.
4. Click and drag all the headers and source files to the project root
5. File/Export Template . . .
6. Now when you open a project based on the template all the files will be there and you can simply click and drag them under the appropriate subfolder.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `Add` -> `New Item...`, I've found that a somewhat clean workaround is to simply drag and drop the files you need into the project. Doing this will include them when exporting the template.